# How to create shapefile size greater than 2GB using GeoTools

Tags: shapefile, geotools, limitations

I am using GeoTools for merging my individual shapefiles but I get an exception when the size of the shapefile increases beyond 2GB.

How can I do this using Geotools?

Comment: You need to use a different data type, e.g. geopackage.

Comment: Shapefile have an "official" size limit of 2GB, you may try to create bigger shapefile but that's not advised as Erik said it's time to try new a output format

Comment: In fact Shapefile can go over 2gb (up to 8gb), GDAL OGR shapefile driver can output shapefile up to 4gb (https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#size-issues) but it's never a good idea to not follow specification as it may causes compatibility problem down the line. I advise you to try Ian Turton answer using geopackage

Answer (score 6):

As everyone said in the comments - you can't. Shapefiles use a 32bit pointer internally and it breaks if you go over 2Gb. Switch to a GeoPackage, fortunately as Datastores are interchangeable all you will need to do is change the parameters you are creating it with.

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.key, "geopkg");
map.put(GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, outFile);
Datastore store = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
```